# getIdToken from firebase.User in typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase-authentication

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class GetRequestsProvider {

  user: firebase.User;
  userIdToken:string;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, authservices: AuthService) {
      afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        this.user = user;
      });
  }

  getUserToken(){

      this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {

          user.getIdToken().then((idToken)=>{

            this.userIdToken = idToken;
            console.log("Here I get the user token correctly: ", this.userIdToken);
            console.log(typeof(this.userIdToken)); // ‘userIdToken’ type is ‘string’

          });

          console.log("Here the variable ‘userIdToken’ is undefined: ", this.userIdToken);
      }     
   }    
}
```

I'm trying to use the [getIdToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken) method from Firebase to authenticate users in my app.

The problem I have now, after successfully getting the user’s token, I am not able to save it into a variable or to use the token somewhere else.

Comment: improved the code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions that return promises (such as `getIdToken`) are asynchronous, and execution of the entire chain happens immediately.  Your console log is *always* going to happen before the token is available.  Whenever the token is finally availalbe, it will be available in the callback that you pass to `then`, and no sooner.  You can only use it there, or to some other function that you pass it to.

Do no go down the route of trying to make `getIdToken()` synchronous or blocking until the token is available - that's not the way it's going to work.  You will need to learn how to work with Firebase APIs asynchronously.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to pass this token to the 'Authorization' header of the HTTP GET request which will authenticate the user in my server's API. The problem is; I cannot use any other of my functions when I try to pass them into `then`, it does not recognise it...
I have seen an example in javascript which pass another function into `then`, but I cannot do it in typescript...

Comment: I would need to get the JSON response from my server's API after the API call is authenticated

Comment: You don't pass anything else "into" `then`.  You call other functions from within the callback.  If this doesn't make sense, then I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding how promises work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Doug, it makes totally sense... Could you please provide a quick sample of how to build the callback to call the function i.e. 'printToken' which would look like this: `printToken(userIdToken ) {

    console.log("tokennnnn ", userIdToken )
  }`

Comment: Just to add some insights, my API is build in Google App Engine, not Firestore, of course after the API calls to my backend are authenticated, I need the JSON responses to use them in the frontend

Comment: You just gave yourself the relevant code.  It's no more complex than calling a function any other time.

Comment: got it! thanks a lot Doug, the key point is to understand how promises work :)